# Snow Leopard Services: targeting all files

Tags: applescript, automator

Here's the available targets for Snow Leopard services in automator.

[Available service targets http://s3.amazonaws.com/augustl-stuff/automator-available-service-targets-84.png](http://s3.amazonaws.com/augustl-stuff/automator-available-service-targets-84.png)

I want my service to operate on all files. It would sort of work to choose "files or folders" and ignore the action if the input is a folder, but that means the service will appear when right clicking folders too, which isn't very elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of any good reasons to why I posted this question here. The answer is pretty obvious; it's not in the list, so it can't be done.